# Order repository in observer returns 'No such entity with orderId' magento 2

Tags: magento2

When event 'controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index' is executed I am trying to get order from database (not the one that will be created after checkout, the one that already exists in database and which is created before.). I am loading order through order repository and **it works**.

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface as OrderRepository;

$this->orderRepository->get($approvalOrderId);
```

When I try to load the same order and with the same code sample when event 'sales_order_place_after' is executed it is not working. I am getting error **'No such entity with orderId = ..'**

Answer (score -1):

It might be that the order is not yet saved at that moment. But the event you are observing will already carry that order object. Can you try the below code in the observers execute function?

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    //do something with the $order
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but as I said I dont want to get the order from observer, I want to get another order which is not related to that event/observer.